# Getting an error while connecting the Mongoose in nodeJs project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error while I connect mongoose to my Nodejs project:

```
/home/shafqat/Downloads/myProgramming/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:278
for (const key of Object.keys(Collection.prototype)) {

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shafqat/Downloads/myProgramming/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:278:42)
```

Attached is a screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31NyH.png)
Any solution ?
Thank you all!

I have tried some solutions but didn't work.

Comment: `enter image description here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, Basically there was an issue with file **"collection.js"** (In my case the entire directory is: `/home/shafqat/Downloads/myProgramming/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js`) , I guess it was because of old version of mongoose or something like this, I uninstalled the mongoose from terminal (`npm uninstall mongoose`) and then I reinstalled mongoose using command: `npm install mongoose`

I worked fine..